# How to handle the Loss connection error and BaseSSHTunnelForwarderError: Could not establish session to SSH gateway

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, sqlalchemy, mysql-python, pymysql

This is my code shown below that i use to connect to the database and get some tables. I have used this for a while without problem but recently I keep on getting this two errors after it runs for a few times. I assume it is something to do with the database. 
Basically what happens is that i can connect to the databases, retrieve my table but since my data is very huge I do it on a for loop where I loop through dates within a given range and get the data. For example I start from 20160401 and count one by one until 20170331(about 365 loops).
However after i run like 20 loops  i get this error s

> OperationError "Lost connection to MySQL server during query (%s)" %
>   (e,))

and sometimes this one below

> BaseSSHTunnelForwarderError: Could not establish session to SSH
>   gateway

I would like to solve this errors but if it is not possible I would like to wait for a few seconds then reconnect to the databases automatically then execute the same query. Any help in solving this will be highly appreciated.

```
import pymysql

from sshtunnel import SSHTunnelForwarder   
with SSHTunnelForwarder(
        (ssh_host, ssh_port),
        ssh_username=ssh_user,
        ssh_pkey=mypkey,
        remote_bind_address=(sql_ip, sql_port)) as tunnel:
        conn = pymysql.connect(host='127.0.0.1', 
                user=sql_username,
                passwd=sql_password, 
                port=tunnel.local_bind_port,
                db=db,charset='ujis')
        data = pd.read_sql_query(query_2, conn,)
```

This is what I have tried so far  but it is not working

```
while True:
        try:
            with SSHTunnelForwarder(
                    (ssh_host, ssh_port),
                    ssh_username=ssh_user,
                    ssh_pkey=mypkey,
                    remote_bind_address=(sql_ip, sql_port)) as tunnel:
                conn = pymysql.connect(host='127.0.0.1',
                                       user=sql_username,
                                       passwd=sql_password,
                                       port=tunnel.local_bind_port,
                                       db=db, charset='ujis')
                data = pd.read_sql_query(query, conn)
            break
        except pymysql.err.OperationalError as e:
            conn.ping(reconnect=True)
```

Comment: Is this related to pandas?

Comment: I use pd.read_sql_query() so a little bit related

Comment: I have same issue also. In my case `OperationError` raised in `pymysql.connect`, so i think `pd.read_sql_query` not related to this problem.